# submit a form with a link from another page

Tags: php, html

I have created 3 php pages. The 1st includes the following form:

```
<form method="POST" name="go" action="search_form_all.php"  >
  <input name="value" type="text" id="search_form_1" size="65" placeholder="enter name"/>
  <input type="submit" value="" name="submit" />
</form>
```

The 2nd page called "search_form_all.php" includes the php codes that displays the results of the above form. So if the user type a name in form and press submit, the "search_form_all.php" displays all names from my database according to what the user inserts in the search form.

All I want is to have in my 3rd php page a link, that when the user press it to execute the form in 1st page. For example if I enter a name in search form like "john", then I want to be able to go to my third page and press the link, the form to be executed and to return all names "john" from my database. Is this possible?

Comment: if its the same user that entered 'john' in the form on page one, you can store that in a session and reuse it when he press the link on page 3

Comment: what you want to do you need search which you get in search_form_all.php (display search result).where you want link first page or second page

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible with session variables. An example:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['views'])) {
        $_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views'];
    } else {
        $_SESSION['views']=1;
    }

    echo "Views=". $_SESSION['views'];
?>
```

You can also refer to [Document Link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: do I have to use this code under my form? And what will be an example of my link in the third page?

Comment: link will be simple as normal link
you just have to get value from session as mention in my answer like $name = $_SESSION['search_name'];